# How do we know that received a new reply message on teams by ms graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We get the message detail by use teams/team-id/channels/channel-id. But when send a new reply message on teams, the parent message's lastmodieddatetime is not changed.

How do we know that received a new reply message on teams by ms graph api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chatMessage.lastModifiedDateTime changes only when the message changes like edits. See [chatMessage properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessage?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties).

For your scenario, You can use [change notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0) on the channel messages. See [change notifications with resource data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks-with-resource-data)